# Loop to get LDAP entries in PHP script

Tags: php, arrays, ldap

Getting LDAP data through PHP by using ldap_connect function I want to list all the objectclass items available.

I got the variable $entries from [here](http://www.geekshangout.com/php-example-get-data-active-directory-via-ldap/)  so I can print a single entry of my LDAP server when executing the following line:

```
var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][0]);
```

For entries with multiple values I am able to do it one by one, I mean:

```
var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][0]);
var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][1]);
var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][2]);
```

But I can't get it inside of a for loop like this and I don't understand why:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    echo $i;
    var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][$i]);
}
```

Actually, my purpose is to do it without knowing the maximum number of objectclass I have, so I want to do it within a while loop looking for the objectclass values until I find the NULL value, something like:

```
$i=0;
while (var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][$i]) != NULL){
    var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What if you `var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"]);`

Comment: @mkaatman No error, just no output. `var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"])` works! Thanks! I'm still curious about why my loops attempts were not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `count` item to iterate the values:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $entries[0]['objectclass']['count']; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    var_dump($entries[0]["objectclass"][$i]);
}
```